# Taking Incremental Back up for SharePoint 2013 Site

Tags: backup, restore, stsadm, disaster-recovery

We created a task scheduler to run a bat file which has this code to take the incremental back up of the site.

> "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\BIN\stsadm" -o backup -url http://xyz -filename
>   D:\SP_Backups\abc.bak -backupmethod differential -nositelock
>   -overwrite

The back up is doing fine every night but i am having a feeling it is taking really long. the back up file is about 9gb. it tooks about 4 hours to do it.

Is it normal or can we do something to speed up the process ?

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to backup the site collection of farm? Looks like it is farm back up.

> When the **url parameter** is used, a backup of the site collection is
>   created. However when the **backupmethod parameter** is used, a backup of
>   an individual database, Web application, or the entire farm can be
>   created.

Their is one more property which can help you increasing the backup time.You can use   [[-backupthreads]](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287967(v=office.12).aspx)  butthis has some pros and cons.

> The number of threads that should be used during the backup. For
>   Windows SharePoint Services, the **recommended value is 3 threads**. The
>   default value is 1. T**he fewer the threads, the easier it is to read
>   and understand the backup log file**.